# How can I know the version of node being used by my meteor app?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have installed meteor under linux, and I don't really know which version of node.js meteor is using.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

***Answer for MacOS and Meteor > v1.1***

The `node` binary resides in the dev_bundle of the meteor-tool:

> ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.3/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin

```
$ cd ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.1.3/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin
$ ./node -v
v0.10.36
```

*Note: The meteor-tool version does **not** match the version of Meteor, but in 99% of the cases you can assume that the latest version is used for your current Meteor.*

At least in **Meteor >= 1.5** you can also directly access the NodeJS bundled with Meteor and find out the version:

```
meteor node -v
```

*Credits to Mickael for pointing that out.*

Answer (score 16):

I just typed `meteor node -v` while in a meteor application and got v0.10.43 back on the CLI.

When I just type `node -v` I get v5.5.0 as a return value.

Comment: One more options would be to run `meteor shell` and then check `process.versions.node`.

Answer (score 11):

In Meteor 1.2.1 you can find a file called `.node_version.txt` in `.meteor/local/build/` folder.

Answer (score 7):

I found this [post](https://forums.meteor.com/t/which-nodejs-version-does-meteor-1-3-2-4-use/25616/4) on the Meteor forum.

Use

```
meteor node -v
```

to know the nodejs version being used by the meteor.

Answer (score 4):

<s>Just plain `node -v` should tell you.</s>
UPDATED:
At least on Debianish systems, meteor installs its own copy of node in /usr/lib/meteor/bin, so `/usr/lib/meteor/bin/node -v` should tell you. If it's not there, it might be in /usr/local/lib...
On my Debian system, the version is 0.6.17.

Comment: So I should assume that meteor is running on top of system node installation? I thought it wasn't

Comment: This is obsolete with newer Meteor versions. Each Meteor application has its own node installation, which is bundled with Meteor. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014750/how-can-i-know-the-version-of-node-being-used-by-my-meteor-app/29507503#29507503

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to check the [History.md](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md) file on the github project. While I'm wiriting this answer, the last update was on meteor 0.5.5, where they updated node.js to v0.8.18.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me. Somewhere between Meteor 0.8 and Meteor 1.1 they've changed the way Node is used. Looking at the https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md is a bit tedious to find out which version is used in the Meteor version you're using, but at least you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mnode](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mnode), but it seems it doesn't work with meteor 0.9. I also recommend reading this [Arunoda article](https://meteorhacks.com/how-meteor-uses-node.html). It has an alternative approach at the end.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me they require now a later version:

`Meteor requires Node v0.10.40 or later.`

was the error I receiver when I had v0.10.36 installed. A good tool for nodejs version management is https://www.npmjs.com/package/n