# path has no method 'parse' in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, path

I have tried this code in meteor js but it will display error "TypeError: Object #Object> has no method 'parse'"

```
path = Npm.require('path')
filename = path.parse('/home/user/dir/file.txt')
```

but in the documentaion in node js parse method should exisit in path library http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_pathstring

Any tips?

Comment: This will only work on the server. Are you running it in client code?

Comment: @DavidWeldon yes I am running it in the server side. I tried resolve method in path. It works but parse I got this error.

Comment: [path.parse](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_pathstring) was included in version 0.12.0. So, if you're running an older version of node, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs default to the current version of node, however meteor typically uses and older version. You can determine which version of node meteor is currently running by looking at the [changelog](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md). For `v.1.0.3.2` it's node `v0.10.33`. You can access the old docs here:

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.33/api/

As you can see, the older version of `path` did not have the `parse` function. You can also see this via:

```
console.log(_.keys(path));
```

If you want to know what version you are using, this post will help you :
[How can I know the version of node being used by my meteor app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014750/how-can-i-know-the-version-of-node-being-used-by-my-meteor-app)