# Is there a list of prescribed Node vesions for each Meteor release?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Is there a list of prescribed Node vesions for each Meteor release?

Given the plethora of changes over the past year, I want to make sure I am using the right node version when running a demeteorized app.

Simple question...haven't been able to find it anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014750/how-can-i-know-the-version-of-node-being-used-by-my-meteor-app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply type `meteor node --version` to get the current Node version for your global Meteor... You might be surprised.

As for the exact Node version for previous Meteor releases, simply look through the Meteor GitHub repo [change log file](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/History.md).

Meteor 1.4 should upgrade to Node version 4+.

Comment: so if i have 20 apps with diff meteor versions & am manually demeteorizing, i'd have to keep track of recommended node versions for all of them (by reading through a changelog file)? Quite a pain...

Comment: also..the changelog does not mention when it was updated from 0.10.41 to 0.10.43 (only important because im trying to debug some compile issues on windows)

Comment: If you need to automatically retrieve the compatible version of Node for each of your Meteor projects, you can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33985662/5108796). In short, look for content of `.meteor/local/build/.node_version.txt` file.