# Meteor app crashes periodically with a Mongo error

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Meteor app crashes every two-three minutes with this error:

```
TypeError: Error.captureStackTrace is not a function
    at Error.MongoError (/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.1.5.45.1i7w6an++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:13:9)
    at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.1.5.45.1i7w6an++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:29:11)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/npm-mongo/.1.5.45.1i7w6an++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:161:20)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:332:8)
    at _runOnTimeout (timers.js:524:11)
    at _makeTimerTimeout (timers.js:515:3)
    at Timer.unrefTimeout (timers.js:584:5)
```

This started after I updated my project to Meteor 1.4. Is Meteor doing something in the background? How can I debug it to find out what's going on?

Additional details: I'm using React, react-router and reactrouter:react-router-ssr. So there is server side rendering. Maybe this will trigger something...

Guys. The most important detail as I see it is this:
`Error.captureStackTrace is not a function`
This is a core node function! If I run node and enter `Error` I see the function: `captureStackTrace: [Function: captureStackTrace]`. So the issue looks like Meteor is maybe running an older version of node that doesn't have `captureStackTrace` in `Error` yet? Well, I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014750/how-can-i-know-the-version-of-node-being-used-by-my-meteor-app) to check the version:

```
MonsterMac:/ alex$ cd ~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.4.0-1/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/
MonsterMac:bin alex$ ./node -v
v4.4.7
```

According to the [Change log](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V4.md#4.4.7) `captureStackTrace` is there in version 4.4.7. Now what?

Comment: The real error is coming from a Mongo connection timeout error. Are you using Meteor's local Mongo instance or connecting to a different Mongo server?

Comment: I'm using the local mongo instance.

Comment: What do you see when you run `meteor node -v`?

Comment: what's the `meteor --version`  ?

Comment: @KingJulian Did you ever found out what was it? I am still experiencing this error.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor uses node 4.4.7. Also, with Meteor 1.4, Mongo is updated to a newer version. To resolve this error, try meteor reset. This will refresh Mongo to the latest version, when you start meteor next.

Comment: Yes, that was done right after Meteor has been updated. The app wouldn't start without updating the database. The app is working but the server side crashes periodically with this error.